# How to install 32-bit libGL.so.1 on 64-bit Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'd like to run 32-bit software on my 64-bit Ubuntu 21.10 and I got an error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's because the library is 64-bit. So I tried to install 32-bit version of it but it doesn't work.

Firstly I've added i386 architecture to my Ubuntu

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and then I tried to install library:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libgl1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed or
                 x-session-manager or
                 x-window-manager or
                 x-terminal-emulator
        Recommends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed or
                    x-session-manager
        Recommends: xserver-xephyr but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xserver-xorg but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: zenity but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-session-bin : Depends: libegl1 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.33.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-mutter-8 (>= 40.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmutter-8-0 (>= 40.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:3.25.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-user-docs but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed or
                           gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How to solve it?

Thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.